# JavaScript fetch to Spotify API returns response body with strange encoding / strange characters

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, svelte, spotify, sveltekit

I am making a SvelteKit application which uses the Spotify API. Right now I'm trying to create a playlist through the API and grab the playlist ID from the response body. I am making a POST request to `https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/myusernamehere/playlists` with the following code:

```js
// create playlist
const fetchUrl = PUBLIC_SPOTIFY_API_URI+`/users/${user_id}/playlists`
const headers = {
    'Authorization': authHeader,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
const createPlaylistResponse = await fetch(fetchUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'Playlist Name',
        description: 'A description',
        public: false
    }),
    headers
})
if (!createPlaylistResponse.ok) {
    const err = await createPlaylistResponse.text()
    throw error(createPlaylistResponse.status, JSON.stringify(err))
}
console.log(createPlaylistResponse.status)
```

I know it works because I see the new playlist on my Spotify account, and I also receive a `201 Created` response text every time. But like I said I need the playlist ID so I can actually add tracks to the playlist. The ID is included in the response body in JSON format, as described in the [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/create-playlist). But `createPlaylistResponse.json()` fails to parse the response's body. Next I tried `createPlaylistResponse.text()` and it returns this:

```
���OO�0���)��i�T�T���mW��u2�c�)mQ�;��GiE�[��������"�K���5
P�2�4=s��j�@�xŘ�tc��-*Ŵ��Zj���@�u$ȍ�:
C!)?o
�D��dx�@���6}\O8����wq�L��.+��ɬ1�BU���YߊEF�t�����p�a=�l�S>��^��#%~���?���K?�`Ri ���P��=>��"�S�5�5���w���蔖2O�͝O,�+�4Ua+�;�g���hr�[�G��AQ������J�g�l�jQ�M�C��`�va�)�A�d�d@��9�:f���<lVq�q�¼�y9MnF�d��%�˸ �xG.�d\Ļ�n~=���ZM�sV��(LV���;�
�v`����XĠ��p0h��>ʻ�2M=lIE� *�����њ��{����z��7���<b}:
```

I tried making the request through Postman with the exact same parameters and I correctly received the response body in JSON format:

```
{
  "collaborative" : false,
  "description" : null,
  "external_urls" : {
    "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/JmaQTtPsnZ14Qo8FrcManM"
  },
  "followers" : {
    "href" : null,
    "total" : 0
  },
  "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/JmaQTtPsnZ14Qo8FrcManM",
  "id" : "JmaQTtPsnZ14Qo8FrcManM",
  ...
}
```

I have made similar GET requests to Spotify API all throughout my app but now I'm running into this issue with a POST request and I am not sure what to do.

Here are the [response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNYA7.png) if that's any help.

Comment: It's likely to do with the response being `chunked` (see the headers.) You may need to re-structure the fetch call to deal with it. Maybe this will help https://gist.github.com/jfsiii/034152ecfa908cf66178

Comment: I would start by making sure you are sending the exact headers as your postman example. postman will usually send some default headers as well. Look in the console of postman for the exact request/response. As for chunked response, I believe fetch will take care of that unless you explicitly add code to pull the chunked stream.

Comment: @Ralph: It should. SvelteKit uses `undici` for the server-side fetch implementation which does appear to support chunked data. Maybe something is throwing it off, like the combination of chunking + gzipping.

Comment: (Actually, `undici` should only be used on Node versions which do not have native `fetch` support, so the version used could be important.)

Comment: I also see gzip in headers. We could be seeing the raw compressed response. Perhaps the undici version used doesn't support gzip?

Comment: @Ralph: That was my very first suspicion, but It does support it, I tested that locally. (It would be a very unhelpful library if it didn't, really.)